# Session is not abandoned on logging out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, logout

I am working on a MVC 4 application, I am new bee to MVC. I have a Actionlink for logout but when I click on that the ActionResult method is not called.
can anyone tell me where am I making a mistake?

_Layout.chtml:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        @if (Session["LoggedinUser"] != null){
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("LogOut", "Login", "Home")</li>}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Clear();
    Session.RemoveAll();
    Session.Abandon();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
}
```

Comment: Logoff is POST and therefore you cannot trigger it using actionlink, which is GET

Comment: yes changing POST to GET works! Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameters are in the wrong order, so you're actually calling the `Login` action:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
    string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
```

Should be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Whatever Text You Want", "LogOut", "Home")
```

Comment: I think hers parameters are in correct order he just by mistake wrote Login instead of Logout

Comment: @AlexArt. I'm just going with what I see, and what I see is the parameters obviously in the wrong order.

Comment: Definitely combine this answer with the comment from Ibrahim ben Salah in the question - your action with `[HttpPost]` won't respond to a GET request. Based on what you have, you should be able to remove that attribute and you'll be fine, after you fix the parameter order.

Comment: this change works with the change of HttpPOST to HttpGET. Thanks! I appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

@Html.ActionLink("LogOut", "Login", "Home")

} try

@Html.ActionLink("LogOut", "LogOut", "Home")

}.

This will work for you..